# PHP: Instanciating namespaced classes

Tags: php, oop

I can't get dynamic instantiating of classes in PHP to work when my files are namespaced. 
PHP seems to be completely ignorant of the `use` keywords on top of my files, as I try to instantiate classes dynamically based upon the value of a variable.

Is there a good solution to this, besides hardcoding the namespace when dynamically instantiating classes?

Here's some quick samples to show what I mean:

Code `new two('one')`; results in that the class one isn't found with the below two files being included:

**File1:**

```
namespace uno;
use dos;

class one {
    function __construct($what) {
        new $what;
    }
}
```

**File2:**

```
namespace dos;
class two { }
```

**File 3:**

```
new one('two'); // Doesn't work!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either full-qualified

```
new \uno\one('two');
```

or defined by `use`

```
use uno\one;
new one('two');
```

or (relative) qualified (but that makes not much sense with a one-level namespace)

```
use uno;
new uno\one('two');
```

With deeper namespace it makes more sense

```
use path\to\myNamespace; 
        new myNamespace\foo\BarClass;
```

or put it in the same namespace

```
namespace uno;
new one('two');
```

See http://php.net/language.namespaces.rules

Comment: Hi! I am not using a one-level namespace, but to simplify here to get some answers without having people all to confused, I deciced to skip them in my example

Comment: Doesn't matter: it doesn't make much sense with a one-level namespace ;) With deeper namespaces it makes more sense `use path\to\myNamespace; new myNamespace\foo\BarClass;` Note, how the identifier after `new` starts with the last part of the namespace in the `use` statement.

Comment: The issue from my point is that PHP ignores the `use` keyword for my dynamic instantiations of classes, ie. `new $what`. Any idea about that?

Comment: Use full-qualified classnames. Its not that hard ;)